# How read a conversation using Gmail.java

Tags: android, gmail, message

I need to read gmail messages/conversation to make a program for blind people.
I'm using [Gmail.java](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#v3mHo8xm6HM/SampleProviders/src/com/verizon/samples/SampleProviders/Gmail.java&q=gmail.java%20android%20read&sa=N&cd=4&ct=rc) to access gmail database. The problem its that i dont know how to access to the body of the mails.

Anyone can help me?

A small excerpt of my code:

Uri uri = Uri.parse(
                Gmail.AUTHORITY_PLUS_CONVERSATIONS + account + "/");
        Cursor cursorConversacion = contentResolver.query(
                uri, Gmail.CONVERSATION_PROJECTION, null, null, null);

```
    int j = 1;
    //Comprobamos que hay cursor
    if (cursorConversacion.moveToFirst()){

        Gmail gmail = new Gmail(mContext.getContentResolver());
        ConversationCursor cc = new ConversationCursor(gmail,account,cursorConversacion);

        do{
            String cuenta = cc.getAccount();
            String snippet = cc.getFromSnippetInstructions();
            String subject = cc.getSubject();
            String numMessages = "" +  cc.getNumMessages();
            String conversationID = "" + cc.getConversationId();

            Log.d("DEBUG","\n\n\n MENSAJES " + j + " \n\n" + 
                    " ID: " + conversationID +
                    " Num messages: " + numMessages + 
                    " Subject: " + subject + 
                    "\nCuenta: " + cuenta +
                    " snippet: " + snippet


            );

            //MessageCursor a partir de la conversacion
            Uri uriMessages = Uri.parse(
                    Gmail.AUTHORITY_PLUS_CONVERSATIONS + account + "/" + conversationID + "/messages");
            Cursor cursorMessages = contentResolver.query(
                    uri, Gmail.MESSAGE_PROJECTION, null, null, null);


            if (cursorMessages.moveToFirst()){
                int k=1;
                do{
                    MessageCursor mc = new MessageCursor(gmail, contentResolver, account, cursorMessages);
                    Log.d("DEBUG","Mensaje " + k + " " + mc.getBody());

                    k++;
                }while ( (k < 10) && (cursorMessages.moveToNext()) ) ;

            }



            j++;
        }while ( (j< 20) && (cursorConversacion.moveToNext()) );

    }
```

The problem is that i don’t know how to access to the mail’s body.

The access to conversation works but the messageCursor doesn’t. I know/believe that the use of messageCursor isn't for message(a message of a conversation), and **i know** that the use of undecommented provider is a bad idea (if you have a better one tell me, please!!!!) but it is the better solution i found to solve my problem.

Ty for help, and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autoanswer :D

```
public void getMails(Context mContext){
    String account="blablabla_accountgmail@gmail.com";
    ContentResolver contentResolver= mContext.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ACCOUNT_URI, null, null, null, null);



    Uri uri = Uri.parse(
            Gmail.AUTHORITY_PLUS_CONVERSATIONS + account + "/");
    Cursor cursorConversacion = contentResolver.query(
            uri, Gmail.CONVERSATION_PROJECTION, null, null, null);

    int j = 1;
    //check cursor
    if (cursorConversacion.moveToFirst()){

        Gmail gmail = new Gmail(mContext.getContentResolver());
        ConversationCursor cc = new ConversationCursor(gmail,account,cursorConversacion);

        do{ //extract some data for the example
            String cuenta = cc.getAccount();
            String snippet = cc.getFromSnippetInstructions();
            String subject = cc.getSubject();
            String numMessages = "" +  cc.getNumMessages();
            String conversationID = "" + cc.getConversationId();

            Log.d("DEBUG","\n\n\n MENSAJES " + j + " \n\n" + 
                    " ID: " + conversationID +
                    " Num messages: " + numMessages + 
                    " Subject: " + subject + 
                    "\nCuenta: " + cuenta +
                    " snippet: " + snippet


            );


            MessageCursor mc = new Gmail(contentResolver).getMessageCursorForConversationId(account, cc.getConversationId());


            if (mc.getCursor().moveToFirst()){
                int k=1;
                do{
                    //MessageCursor mc = new MessageCursor(gmail, contentResolver, account, cursorMessages);
                    Log.d("DEBUG","Mensaje " + k + " " + mc.getBody());
                    Log.d("DEBUG",mc.getFromAddress());

                    k++;
                }while ( (k < 10) && (mc.next()) ) ;

            }



            j++;
        }while ( (j< 20) && (cursorConversacion.moveToNext()) );

    }
```

THIS CODE USES Gmail.java (link in my question post) and it's an example to extract the body of an emails. You can extract other attributes like mailFrom or date send